# Graph DB (Neo4J) - how to keep states? As nodes or properties?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

What is the better way to keep nodes states in graph db (Neo4J)?
As another nodes, or just like properites?

Example:
I have several nodes and I want them to choose if they are active or not. Should I create node `Active` and connect to it with relations, or should I make property `status: Active` in them?

What is better from performance point of view and easiness of querying?

Comment: This blog post related to a similar question will help you http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/01/16/neo4j-graph-model-design-labels-versus-indexed-properties.html

Comment: I'd probably use an `:Active` label or less likely an `active=true` property